# How to get a mapping of country codes to international number prefixes in Python?

Tags: python, phone-number

I'm interested in getting a mapping of country codes to international phone number prefixes, like so:

```
{'US': '+1', 'GB': '+44', 'DE': '+49', ...}
```

One library that probably contains this information is [`python-phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers). However, after a quick perusal of the source code I wasn't able to find where this information is stored. For example, the  `shortdata/region_DE.py` module looks like this:

```
"""Auto-generated file, do not edit by hand. DE metadata"""
from ..phonemetadata import NumberFormat, PhoneNumberDesc, PhoneMetadata

PHONE_METADATA_DE = PhoneMetadata(id='DE', country_code=None, international_prefix=None,
    general_desc=PhoneNumberDesc(national_number_pattern='1\\d{2,5}', possible_length=(3, 6)),
    toll_free=PhoneNumberDesc(national_number_pattern='116\\d{3}', example_number='116000', possible_length=(6,)),
    emergency=PhoneNumberDesc(national_number_pattern='11[02]', example_number='112', possible_length=(3,)),
    short_code=PhoneNumberDesc(national_number_pattern='11(?:[025]|6(?:00[06]|1(?:1[17]|23)))', example_number='115', possible_length=(3, 6)),
    short_data=True)
```

It seems like the `country_code` and `international_prefix` fields are `None`. How can I get such a mapping (possibly with a different library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the mapping you want using [`pycountry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) and [`phonenumbers`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers), along with a simple dictionary comprehension:

```
import phonenumbers as pn
import pycountry

dct = {c.alpha_2: pn.country_code_for_region(c.alpha_2) for c in pycountry.countries}
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'SK': 421, 'KI': 686, 'LV': 371, 'GH': 233, 'JP': 81, 'SA': 966, 'TD': 235, 'SX': 1, 'CY': 357, 'CH': 41, 'EG': 20, 'PA': 507, 'KP': 850, 'CO': 57, 'GW': 245, 'KG': 996, 'AW': 297, 'FM': 691, 'SB': 677, 'HR': 385, 'PY': 595, 'BG': 359, 'IQ': 964, 'ID': 62, 'GQ': 240, 'CA': 1, 'CG': 242, 'MO': 853, 'SL': 232, 'LA': 856, 'OM': 968, 'MP': 1, 'DK': 45, 'FI': 358, 'DO': 1, 'BM': 1, 'GN': 224, 'NE': 227, 'ER': 291, 'DE': 49, 'UM': 0, 'CM': 237, 'PR': 1, 'RO': 40, 'AZ': 994, 'DZ': 213, 'BW': 267, 'MK': 389, 'HN': 504, 'IS': 354, 'SJ': 47, 'ME': 382, 'NR': 674, 'AD': 376, 'BY': 375, 'RE': 262, 'PG': 675, 'SO': 252, 'NO': 47, 'CC': 61, 'EE': 372, 'BN': 673, 'AU': 61, 'HM': 0, 'ML': 223, 'BD': 880, 'GE': 995, 'US': 1, 'UY': 598, 'SM': 378, 'NG': 234, 'BE': 32, 'KY': 1, 'AR': 54, 'CR': 506, 'VA': 39, 'YE': 967, 'TR': 90, 'CV': 238, 'DM': 1, 'ZM': 260, 'BR': 55, 'MG': 261, 'BL': 590, 'FJ': 679, 'SH': 290, 'KN': 1, 'ZA': 27, 'CF': 236, 'ZW': 263, 'PL': 48, 'SV': 503, 'QA': 974, 'MN': 976, 'SE': 46, 'JE': 44, 'PS': 970, 'MZ': 258, 'TK': 690, 'PM': 508, 'CW': 599, 'HK': 852, 'LB': 961, 'SY': 963, 'LC': 1, 'IE': 353, 'RW': 250, 'NL': 31, 'MA': 212, 'GM': 220, 'IR': 98, 'AT': 43, 'SZ': 268, 'GT': 502, 'MT': 356, 'BQ': 599, 'MX': 52, 'NC': 687, 'CK': 682, 'SI': 386, 'VE': 58, 'IM': 44, 'AM': 374, 'SD': 249, 'LY': 218, 'LI': 423, 'TN': 216, 'UG': 256, 'RU': 7, 'DJ': 253, 'IL': 972, 'TM': 993, 'BF': 226, 'GF': 594, 'TO': 676, 'GI': 350, 'MH': 692, 'UZ': 998, 'PF': 689, 'KZ': 7, 'GA': 241, 'PE': 51, 'TV': 688, 'BT': 975, 'MQ': 596, 'MF': 590, 'AF': 93, 'IN': 91, 'AX': 358, 'BH': 973, 'JM': 1, 'MY': 60, 'BO': 591, 'AI': 1, 'SR': 597, 'ET': 251, 'ES': 34, 'TF': 0, 'GU': 1, 'BJ': 229, 'SS': 211, 'KE': 254, 'BZ': 501, 'IO': 246, 'MU': 230, 'CL': 56, 'MD': 373, 'LU': 352, 'TJ': 992, 'EC': 593, 'VG': 1, 'NZ': 64, 'VU': 678, 'FO': 298, 'LR': 231, 'AL': 355, 'GB': 44, 'AS': 1, 'IT': 39, 'TC': 1, 'TW': 886, 'BI': 257, 'HU': 36, 'TL': 670, 'GG': 44, 'PN': 0, 'SG': 65, 'LS': 266, 'KH': 855, 'FR': 33, 'BV': 0, 'CX': 61, 'AE': 971, 'LT': 370, 'PT': 351, 'KR': 82, 'BB': 1, 'TG': 228, 'AQ': 0, 'EH': 212, 'AG': 1, 'VN': 84, 'CI': 225, 'BS': 1, 'GL': 299, 'MW': 265, 'NU': 683, 'NF': 672, 'LK': 94, 'MS': 1, 'GP': 590, 'NP': 977, 'PW': 680, 'PK': 92, 'WF': 681, 'BA': 387, 'KM': 269, 'JO': 962, 'CU': 53, 'GR': 30, 'YT': 262, 'RS': 381, 'NA': 264, 'ST': 239, 'SC': 248, 'CN': 86, 'CD': 243, 'GS': 0, 'KW': 965, 'MM': 95, 'AO': 244, 'MV': 960, 'UA': 380, 'TT': 1, 'FK': 500, 'WS': 685, 'CZ': 420, 'PH': 63, 'VI': 1, 'TZ': 255, 'MR': 222, 'MC': 377, 'SN': 221, 'HT': 509, 'VC': 1, 'NI': 505, 'GD': 1, 'GY': 592, 'TH': 66}
```

Comment: I found that `phonenumbers` also has a `COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE` constant which maps number prefixes to tuples of country codes (e.g. `1: ('US', 'CA', ...), ...`). This can be 'switched around' using the following dictionary comprehension: `{code: prefix for prefix, codes in phonenumbers.COUNTRY_CODE_TO_REGION_CODE.items() for code in codes}`

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a python library that must be perfect for your problem.
It's called PhoneISO3166.
This is the github link: [GitHub phoneiso3166](https://github.com/onlinecity/phone-iso3166/)